# numberFormatException

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is this sequence correct in android? I am tring to get EditText value and convert it into integer.

`startTime_hour_int=Integer.parseInt(startTime_hour_edittext.getEditableText().toString());`

Because my logcat throws the below error. 
     `05-12 10:26:35.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer`

Can  anyone tell me, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andro_Selva

If textbox startTime_hour_edittext is blank then Integer.parseInt is trying to parse "" into integer thats why you are getting  NumberFormatException

so before use of `startTime_hour_int=Integer.parseInt(startTime_hour_edittext.getEditableText().toString());`

check condition

```
if(!startTime_hour_edittext.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
startTime_hour_int=Integer.parseInt(startTime_hour_edittext.getEditableText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call this code from some kind of listener on the `EditBox`? This can happen when you delete all content from the box. Just check that the text is not empty before parsing it to int.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the condition to check my EditText content. Now the problem has been sorted out. Thanks.