# Android NumberFormatException error with a simple number input from EditText

Tags: android, integer, android-edittext, parseint

So I have a simple Edit-text with number input.
User enters his phone number and it is saved into DB obviously that is the goal.
now every time i do

```
int contactNumber=Integer.parseInt(mContactNumber.getText().toString());
```

I get an error thrown saying NumberFormatException for some reason it doesn't like a string of number. I have made sure that mContactNumber field in the android input field has the

```
android:input="number"
```

now i also tried  just to be sure

```
int contactNumber=Integer.parseInt(mContactNumber.getText().toString().trim());
```

still the same error

Guys any ideas?

Comment: What's in `mContactNumber`, is it an integer?

Comment: what is the field in db is it int or string for contact number?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973493/numberformatexception

Comment: guys no I already have that. All the test of mine that are failing look like... 11-01 23:05:45.634: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1148): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '7777777778' as integer which obviously not empty

Comment: The number you are giving input exceeds the limit of int type & i think that's why its giving NumberFormatException. As i answered , Cast your type to long , I guess that will work for you .....

Comment: any how, you are getting only digits as you have specified input=number then why to use parseInt simply assign it to string and check through regex.

Comment: You should try something like that as hanry said. Using regex u can also check the validity of your input , if it is in your desired phone number format or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the Type to ' long ' instead of ' int '. Hope that will work for you.

Comment: doesn't make sense why that works as in Long.parseLong instead of int when I had the android:input type set for the EditText as numbers.. but ohh well

Comment: Well , two things may have happened. One , your input number was exceeding the range of int type and was in the range of long type , so it worked as u cast type to long. Otherwise , your input number was promoted to long internally , but as you had cast it to int type , exception has been thrown. Anyways , It worked for you that's great. You can further search on internet about the issue if you would like , considering my two points. Lastly , if the answer have solved your problem then accept the answer so that it can be helpful for others who have the same problems. Thanks .....

Answer (score 3):

This might be because you are leaving the text field empty. Are you sure you are not parsing an empty string?

Comment: nope added a comment please check that. Empty token is not the problem which is why it is weird. ohh also using 1.6 version.

Comment: Check this if it helps looks like a similar problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599061/unable-to-parse-as-integer

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a simple condition:

```
if(mContactNumber.getText().length()>0)
{
    int contactNumber=Integer.parseInt(mContactNumber.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

Comment: Just saying I had this exact problem with a number input of '5'. It's String value had a length of 1. Therefore, I don't think this approach would work.

Answer (score 2):

For phone Number you can not take it as Integer. try to take it as string only and after getting that string you can do the check for the numbers only by

```
TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(str);
```

Comment: although in general u are right that the number better be saved in string as even later on I can do a check in form of string like String incommingNumber = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); only if I knew that before

Comment: So do you still facing the Exception? if yes then try with PhoneNumberUtils API

Comment: hi drax, nah solved it using the Long instead of Int. Don't know why it worked though.